# MSBuild handling circular dependencies

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, msbuild

I am new to MSBuild. Just started trying it two days ago, and now I am just testing it. I have run into a problem where I get this error:

```
"c:\Users\martinslot\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MultifileAssembly\SpecializedBuild.xml" (BuildNumberUtil target) (1) ->
  c:\Users\martinslot\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MultifileAssembly\SpecializedBuild.xml(4,34): error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in t
he target dependency graph involving target "BuildNumberUtil".
```

My MSBuild script look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="BuildNumberUtil" DependsOnTargets="BuildStringUtil" >
    <Message Text="=============Building modules for NumberUtil============="/>

    <Csc TargetType="Module" Sources="NumberUtil/DoubleUtil.cs; NumberUtil/IntegerUtil.cs" AddModules="/StringUtil/StringUtil"/>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(NetModules)" DestinationFolder="../Output/Specialized"/>

  </Target>

  <Target Name="BuildStringUtil" DependsOnTargets="BuildNumberUtil" >
    <Message Text="=============Building modules for StringUtil============="/>

    <Csc TargetType="Module" Sources="StringUtil/StringUtil.cs;" AddModules="/NumberUtil/IntegerUtil;/NumberUtil/DoubleUtil"/>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(NetModules)" DestinationFolder="/Output/Specialized"/>

  </Target>
</Project>
```

I understand the problem, actually I created this small example to see if MSBuild understood and could somehow correct the problem. How do I solve this?

My problem is that the two targets compile modules that rely on eachother. Does someone here have a solution on how to handle this kind of problem with MSBuild? Maybe I am constructing this in the wrong way?

Comment: It just can't work.  The solution is trivial with a 3rd project, one that can generate the metadata that the others need.  There's a real case of it in the .NET framework, mscorlib depends on System, System depends on mscorlib.  Whatever bootstrapping mechanism Microsoft used to solved it (.netmodules, maybe, probably intermediary al.exe linked versions) is something you don't want to get in to.

Comment: Oh. I can see now that VS is actually trowing me alert when adding the references by VS GUI interface (right click on references and adding project references). Thanks for the answer, Hans Passant.

Comment: Why are you calling `<Csc>` tasks directly?

Comment: @KMoraz 1)because I want to try MSBuild out 2) because I do not know any better.

Comment: Normally you will let the .csproj files to control the compilation logic. Open any .csproj file and you'll notice it's actually MSBuild file, with pointers to common tasks and project data definitions.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I have not found a way of building moudles this way yet. That is properly because I am not that into MSBuild yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply cannot build projects with circular dependencies. How could you? Which do you build first? There may be some esoteric, convoluted, incorrect way of doing so, but why do it? Circular dependencies usually indicate a design flaw. Fix the design, and you no longer have a circular dependency issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to construct Circular Modules within the scope of MSBuild and Visual Studio; however, doing so has a very limited set of situations where it would be valid to do so.

One key way to do this, if you're planning on using Xaml within your code, is to remove the `Sources` aspect of the `Csc` tag and generate your own `.response` file which actually points to the code you wish to inject.  Within the `Csc` tag attributes you'd specify this file yourself in the `ResponseFiles` attribute.

Within your `.response` file, you would then break your application down into its assembly and netmodule components, making sure to include the core assembly's files first at all times.  Typically the `Csc` tag's attributes are directly translated into Csc.exe command line parameters.  The parameter names do not always match up.  For the sake of resolution it's best to use full, non-relative, paths when referring to files (example, *partial*, `.response` below):

```
"X:\Projects\Code\C#\Solution Name\InternalName\ProjectName - InternalName\SearchContexts\StringSearchType.cs"
"X:\Projects\Code\C#\Solution Name\InternalName\ProjectName - InternalName\UI\Themes\Themes.cs"
/target:module /out:bin\x86\Debug\InternalName.UI.dll
"X:\Projects\Code\C#\Solution Name\InternalName\ProjectName - InternalName\UI\EditDatabaseImageControl.xaml.cs"
"X:\Projects\Code\C#\Solution Name\InternalName\ProjectName - InternalName\obj\x86\Debug\UI\EditDatabaseImageControl.g.cs"
```

You'll notice that this will end up with merging your multiple sets of Targets into one, and that I've included the xaml generated code myself.  This is partly why you remove the Sources aspect, as the Xaml Page generator part of the MSBuild task automatically injects information into the @(Compile) set.  Since there's a Debug/Release configuration, in the area where you define the response file to use, I create two versions of the response (since I'm using a T4 template):

```
ResponseFiles="$(CompilerResponseFile);InternalName.$(Configuration).response"
```

If you intended to include more than one platform in your code you'd likely need C*P response files where C is the number of configurations (Debug|Release) and P is the number of platforms (x86, x64, AnyCpu).  This kind of solution would likely only be a **sane** method by using a generator.

The short version of this: it is possible to create circular modules so long as you can guarantee that you'll compile it all in one step.  To ensure that you maintain the build functionality that is afforded to you with the Xaml build step, your best bet is to start with a normal C# project, and create your own `.Targets` file from the `$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets` in the `<Import ...` tag near the bottom. You'll also likely need a secondary csproj for design purposes since a large portion of intellisense is lost by using this workaround (or use a csproj `Condition` attribute where the target is selected by some flag you set).  You'll also notice certain Xaml editors don't seem to like the binding to netmodule namespaces, so if you bind to types in a netmodule you'll likely have to do them in codebehind (I haven't tested workarounds for this since there's usually ways around static namespace binding)

For some reason within all this, the `.baml` compiled `.xaml` files are implicitly understood by the `Csc` compiler, I haven't been able to figure out where it's deriving this from a command argument, or if it's just implicit by design.  If I had to guess they're inferred by the g.cs files associated to what you include in your list of included files.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that this is occurred for web application (either ASP.NET standard web application or ASP.NET MVC application) and fix for this problem is to be removed the below line in ".csproj" file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>
    $(BuildDependsOn);
    Package
  </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```